# Get SHA1 Checksum from GPG key?

Tags: gnupg, sha1

I'm doing a encryption experience but need some help. I found a Private GPG Key while decrypting an image. Now, what can I do with this key?

The answer I need to find are the first 5 characters of a SHA-1 Checksum. So could I decrypt the GPG Key to get a SHA-1 checksum?

Comment: If it's the actual key you can't decrypt it. You would need some other kind of data to encrypt/decrypt or you could need part of the hash that is part of the key. Look [at this](http://www.spywarewarrior.com/uiuc/ss/sec-key/sec-key.htm) as an example.

Comment: @Seth alright, thanks. I will continue the research then.